# PHP openssl des-ede3-cbc to Golang

Tags: php, go

I've following code in PHP:

```
$l = ceil(strlen($message) / 8) * 8;
$enc = substr(openssl_encrypt($message . str_repeat("\0", $l - strlen($message)), 'des-ede3-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"), 0, $l);
```

How can I implement it in Go?

I tried like this but got different result:

```
    block, err := des.NewTripleDESCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("err: %s", err)
        return
    }

    // Create initialization vector from rand.reader
    iv := make([]byte, des.BlockSize)
    if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, iv); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("err: %s", err)
        return
    }

    // Encrypt with CBC mode
    cipherText := make([]byte, len(plainText))
    encryptMode := cipher.NewCBCEncrypter(block, iv)
    encryptMode.CryptBlocks(cipherText, plainText)

    str := hex.EncodeToString(cipherText)

    fmt.Println("Cipher text: %s", str)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the mistake. I was using `rand.Reader` for `iv` but in PHP was different.

`var iv = []byte{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`

Comment: IVs should be random _per-message_ and are not secret. A common practice is to pack the IV into the first X bytes of the message.